# How to bring up a ViewController when a TableView item is selected?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am writing a application that has two main views. The first is the main screen and the second is a UITableViewController and is populated with a array to display history of the user. The TableView loads fine and populates fine, the problem is when I go to open the main View Controller back up. If I use:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    ViewController *myView;

    myView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];

}
```

The ViewController shows up but the screen is black!

If I use:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    ViewController *myView;

    myView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];

}
```

The application crashes and tells me:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>    (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x30f0a88f 0x35fdb259 0x30f0a789 0x30f0a7ab 0x318a434b 0x318123c7 0x316efc59 0x31665c17 0x31670267
>   0x316701d5 0x3170f59b 0x3170e367 0x317696a7 0x36dc1 0x316de93d
>   0x31758627 0x3094d933 0x30edea33 0x30ede699 0x30edd26f 0x30e604a5
>   0x30e6036d 0x3129f439 0x3165acd5 0x3465b 0x34600) terminate called
>   throwing an exception(lldb)

I am really new to application programming for the iPhone and iPad, but I thought this would be a fairly simple task. I have switched views before in other applications but this one is just not working. Please help!!!

Comment: How does your `UITableViewController` get put onto the screen?  (The meta-answer to your question is to reverse whatever that was so that you go **back** to your main screen instead of trying to duplicate it.)

Comment: How you are creating your ViewController,I mean using nib or programmatically?Can you post your ViewController UI code?

Comment: @NuzhatZari I am using a xib file, or layout, to be displayed. I am not setting up the form through the code. Any code?

Comment: Then check your nib file name and the name you are providing in myView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]], I think it is not same.

Answer (score 0):

AS the error says you dont have a nib file called ViewController, check your project for a nib file called ViewController

Comment: Yes the nib file is there! Thats why I do not understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

3 things:

1) Really consider using a newer xcode and storyboards for simple applications like this (there are arguments for and against storyboards, but if you're a beginner, they are the way to go).

Here's a good document you can follow through: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html

2) Your code:

```
myView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense, unless you're doing something very complicated (and you say you're new to iphone development) - this suggests you are creating a custom UIViewController completely programmatically.

This following code makes more sense, but the error suggests you haven't created ViewController NIB file in your project (ViewController.xib which you edit with Interface Builder).

```
myView = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

3) You say you're created a couple of ViewControllers, but how do you transition between them?  Normally you would use a UINavigationController or UITabBarController to handle transitions (again, unless you're doing something more complex).  These then include mechanisms to allow switching between views.

Going back to my first point - using storyboards makes managing these multiple views a lot more simple.

Comment: Oh, and if you're sure you have created the xib file in your project, check the capitalisation, spelling, etc, and also that it is being included in the bundle (ie. the Target Membership is ticked for the file on the target you are building).

Comment: OK, well I do not know how to included it in the Bundle. The ViewController.m, ViewController.h, and ViewController.xib are all in the project. I will look at the tutorials, Thanks

Comment: It would most likely be included by default.  Look under View->Utilities->Show File Inspector and check the xib file is included in your target (under Target Membership).